# How do i create a cross fading so i can use javascript to call the keyframes in the css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, cross-fade

I am trying to create a fade in and fade out effect on my photos in html. How do I call the keyframes in css to javascript when the image is displayed?

I have to use javascript as part of the requirements for the slideshow

It seems like i have to insert .classlist.add?

```js
var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();

function showSlides() {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("fade");
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  setTimeout(showSlides, 5000);
}
```

```css
@keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@keyframes fadeout {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}
```

```html
    <!-- Images used for slideshow -->
    <div class="fade">
      <figure><img class="img-fluid" src=https://via.placeholder.com/150

C/O https://placeholder.com/"></figure>
    </div>
    <div class="fade">
      <figure><img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150

C/O https://placeholder.com/"> </figure>
    </div>
    <div class="fade">
      <figure><img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150

C/O https://placeholder.com/"></figure>
    </div>
    <div class="fade">
      <figure><img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150

C/O https://placeholder.com/"></figure>
    </div>
    <div class="fade">
      <figure><img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150

C/O https://placeholder.com/eg"></figure>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: For such a simple slider you do not need JS, [check this out](https://codepen.io/davidhc/pen/nLpJk)

Comment: I checked in local.. its working fine.. what do u want form this? plz explain clearly

Comment: i want to target the css keyframes in javascript, for example:  slides[slideIndex-1].style= "fadein" before it displays as block and after that target "fadeout"

Comment: can you upload the images or use something like https://placeholder.com/ so we can provide better help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need keyframes for this:

```js
// Set the delay between slides
const delay = 1000

// Get an array of any elements with a class of 'fade'
const slides = Array.from( document.querySelectorAll('.fade') )

// Function to cycle through each slide, show it, then hide it after the specified delay
const cycleSlides = () => {
  // use Array.forEach to iterate through the elements in the slides array
  slides.forEach( (slide, i) => {

    // Show the slide
    setTimeout( () => {
      showSlide(slide)
    }, delay * i)

    // Hide the slide after the specified delay
    setTimeout( () => {
      hideSlide(slide)
    }, (delay*i)+delay)

  }) // End of map iterator
}

// Function to fade in a single slide
const showSlide = (slide) => {
  //Add the '--in' class
  slide.classList.add('--in')
}

// Function to fade out a single slide
const hideSlide = (slide) => {
  // Remove the '--in' class
  slide.classList.remove('--in')
}

// Call our cycle function for the first time
cycleSlides()

// Restart our cycle function each time it finishes
setInterval( () => {
  cycleSlides()
}, delay*slides.length)
```

```css
.fade {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity .4s ease-in-out;
}
.fade.--in {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="fade">
  <img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/0000FF?text=1" />
</div>
<div class="fade">
  <img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/FF0000?text=2" />
</div>
<div class="fade">
  <img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/FFFF00?text=3" />
</div>
<div class="fade">
  <img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/008000?text=4">
</div>
```

UPDATE: ES5 version at OP's request:

```js
// Set the delay between slides
var delay = 1000

// Get an array of any elements with a class of 'fade'
var slides = Array.from( document.querySelectorAll('.fade') )

// Function to cycle through each slide, show it, then hide it after the specified delay
function cycleSlides() {
    // iterate through the elements in the slides array
    for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {

        // Show the slide
        showSlide(slides[i], delay*i)

        // Hide the slide after the specified delay
        hideSlide(slides[i], (delay*i)+delay)
    } // End of map iterator
}

// Function to fade in a single slide
function showSlide(slide, _delay) {
    //Add the '--in' class
    setTimeout(function() {
        slide.classList.add('--in')
    }, _delay)
}

// Function to fade out a single slide
function hideSlide(slide, _delay) {
    // Remove the '--in' class
    setTimeout(function() {
        slide.classList.remove('--in')
    }, _delay)
}

// Call our cycle function for the first time
cycleSlides()

// Restart our cycle function each time it finishes
setInterval(function() {
    cycleSlides()
}, delay*slides.length)
```

```css
.fade {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity .4s ease-in-out;
}
.fade.--in {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="fade">
  <img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/0000FF?text=1" />
</div>
<div class="fade">
  <img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/FF0000?text=2" />
</div>
<div class="fade">
  <img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/FFFF00?text=3" />
</div>
<div class="fade">
  <img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/008000?text=4">
</div>
```

Comment: I thought the comments were quite clear, I'll add more, give me a few minutes.

Comment: it does not seem to work for me the code. I get five pictures displayed on the website

Comment: Apologies, I forgot to create an array from the NodeList. I've updated the code, it should work now.

Comment: I've tidied it up a bit - added a delay variable, and used an interval to restart the cycle function each time.

Comment: It's still not working but i guess i will try to figure out myself, Thanks for helping

Comment: Working for me in Chrome, unless I've misunderstood? Perhaps your question needs to be clearer in what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Hi @LewisDonovan - I've added your codepen as a Stack snippet so it can be run from within the site. Hope you don't mind!

Comment: Thanks @JamesWhiteley, I've re-added the comments for clarity.

Comment: @LewisDonovan I think the expectation is to have a single image(like a single square div) crossfade into others. In your answer you have five in a row.

Comment: i am trying to do it using function as i am new to javascript. This is what i get: function showslides(figure){
  figure.classList.add("fade");
}
function hideslides(figure){
  figure.classList.remove("fade");
}
var allslides = document.getElementsByTagName("figure");
for(var i=0;i<5;i++){
  setTimeout(function(){},1000);
  setTimeout(function(){},1000);
}

Comment: Ah ok @10101010 in that case you would make the .fade class absolutely positioned in the CSS.

Comment: @HanHongTuck I've added an ES5 version for you - this should match the syntax you're using, but I'd recommend learning modern JavaScript for future projects.